# How to ignore dtype when read file csv using Dask Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a large file csv, it has 9600 columns and each column has a different type. When I read file using `Dask Datafame` and use attribute `head()`, I get error `Mismatched dtypes found in pd.read_csv/pd.read_table`. How can I ignore it. I use pandas read file csv don't have errors but very slow because the size of file is 2.5GB.
Thank!

Comment: That's a lot of columns! How many rows?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your csv file? along with code to import the file?

Comment: depending on your degree of knowledge about the potential data type present in the data set, you may want to cast the data type to string by setting the `dtype` argument in the `read_csv()` function.

Comment: In the foot note of `Dask` doc (), you can read that despite the inference about the data type, the presence of NaN can confuse the csv reader function. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv

Comment: @mdurant It has 129013 rows

Comment: I had a similar issue and forced all columns initially to be of type string: data = dd.read_csv(filename).astype(str)       and then changed column types later on, as necessary  (using lambdas)

Comment: @leoburgy The csv file is dataset for CNN model, so I don't cast the data type to string.

Comment: ^ this doesn't tell us much. You said that the types were string or null, so explicitly loading as str sounds ok, but you have more information than we do.